# After submitting a remote form with Rails, how do I redirect the user to another page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, redirect, remote-forms

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.   I want to submit a form in a modal dialog, so I have set up my form like so

```
<%= form_for @my_object, :remote => true do |f| %>
```

but if the user submits the form successfully, I would like to reload the page that invoked the modal dialog with a notice of “Saved Successfully.”  I can’t figure out what I need to put in my “format.js” to make this happen.  This is what I have in my controller so far …

```
  def create
    @my_object = MyObject.new(my_object_params)
    @current_user = User.find(session["user_id"])
    @my_object.user = @current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      if @my_object.save
        format.html { redirect_to controller: "users", action: "index", notice: 'Saved successfully.' }
        format.js   { render action: ‘../users/index’, notice: ‘Saved Successfully’, location: @my_object }
      else
        format.html { render action: "index" }
        format.js   { render json: @my_object.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Right now, a successful submission results in a 500 error complaining about missing partials when I try and execute the above.  Pretty sure what I have is wrong anyway.

Comment: Why do not want to use simple html version without `remote: true` ? if u want to redirect it.

Comment: Agreed with @7urkm3n. Adding a redirect/reload defeats the purpose of using a remote form.

Comment: Per my comment to the other poster, if there are validation errors, I want those to be displayed in the modal window.  Otherwise, I would have to reload my page and respawn the window and that looks messy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
#app/controllers/redirect.rb
...

format.js { render js: "window.location='#{url.to_s}'" }

...
```

If you like keeping things separated, just put `format.js` in your controller and do the javascript redirect in your view (redirect.js.erb)

In both cases, just set flash[:notice] to whatever you need before redirecting.

Answer (score 3):

> redirect_to events_path, format: 'js'

For this you will need to have events/index.js.erb in your file structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you are redirecting anyway, you might as well avoid the remote/AJAX call, and just redirect from the create action.

```
<%= form_for @my_object do |f| %>
```

and

```
def create
  @my_object = MyObject.new(my_object_params)
  ...
  redirect_to some_path
end
```

Comment: But in this situation, how do I display validation errors?  If I'm submitting it without AJAX, I have to reload the page, then respawn the modal window and I don't like the way that looks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have want to redirect it after successfully `create/updated` and just use `.html` method. Otherwise just use JS option like in this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-page-redirect-using-jquery).

```
  def create
    @my_object = MyObject.new(my_object_params.merge(user: User.find(session["user_id"])))
    respond_to do |format|
      if @my_object.save
        format.html { redirect_to controller: "users", action: "index", notice: 'Saved successfully.' }
      else
      ....
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: You're saying just remove my "format.js" block in the success branch?  I tried taht, but it didn't work.  I saw this in my log, "Processing by UsersController#index as JS" but yet on my client side nothing happened.

Comment: Yeah but if I do that, how will I dynamically display validation errors?  Since this is a modal window, submitting a normal form would require my reloading the page and respawning that window, and per my other comments, that just looks bad.

Comment: @Dave, `render` is not refreshing a page, but if its in modal then u gotta make it in `JS`, try `format.json{render json: @obj.errors}` and handle it through ajax. it should be if not success !

Answer (score 0):

That will help you, from your controller

```
render :js => "window.location = '/jobs/index'"
```